# MongoDB authentication error while running from nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose

Im trying to connect to mongo db by running mongo server by --auth option. In the below code 'sample' db is dynamic. How can I put a entry for adding username and password for 'sample' db by nodejs.

```
//Admin user name and password created through mongo shell
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://username:password@localhost/admin'); 
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
conn.once('open', function callback () {
//Dynamic DB creation 
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://username:password@localhost/sample');
conn.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
conn.once('open', function callback () {

console.log('\nDatabase is opened...\n')

});
```

The above line throws error since 'sample' db is not authenticated. How can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created the user already?  If you likely to authenticate against the sample db you have to create the user there first. (You cannot create users if you have not done a userAdmin user before setting the --auth option). Do you have any users defined? If you created the userAdmin roled user you have to authenticate against the admin database which is a dedicated one for cluster wide users

Comment: @attish Through mongo shell I have done userAdmin roled user and authenticated also. From shell Im able to create static new db and set user name and password. But for dynamic db the same process I have to do through nodejs

Comment: @attish I have edited my code. plz check it.

Comment: Have you tried to specify the port too?

Comment: @attish Yes have tried with port too.